# Find and replace specific characters in a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Let's say I have a string variable called `str` containing the value below:

```
~Header 1~
*Content 1*
*Content 2*

~Header 2~
*Content 1*
*Content 2*
*Content 3*

~Header 3~
*Content 1*
```

What I want is to replace the special character which is the `~` with `<b>Header</b>`and `*` with `<p>Content</p>` so it will result in:

```
<b>Header 1</b>
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>

<b>Header 2</b>
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
<p>Content 3</p>

<b>Header 3</b>
<p>Content 1</p>
```

and then remove the NewLine and replace it with `<br/>` and make it in just one line.

So far I can just remove the NewLine and replace it with `<br/>` and then make it in just one line.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
<b>Header 1</b><br/><p>Content 1</p><br/><p>Content 2</p><br/><br/><b>Header 2</b><br/><p>Content 1</p><br/><p>Content 2</p><br/><p>Content 3</p><br/><br/><b>Header 3</b><br/><p>Content 1</p>
```

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
Dim str As String = TextBox.Text ' The String Value is inputted from TextBox with Multiline property

Dim newStr As String = Regex.Replace(str, vbLf, "<br/>")
newStr = Regex.Replace(str, vbCr, "<br/>")
MessageBox.Show(newStr)
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

```
~Header 1~<br/>*Content 1*<br/>*Content 2*<br/><br/>~Header 2~<br/>*Content 1*<br/>*Content 2*<br/>*Content 3*<br/><br/>~Header 3~<br/>*Content 1*
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "~" and "*" characters always appear at the start and end of lines, you can use the following method

- Use `String.Split` to create an array with one element for each line of `str`.
- Loop through the lines and make the substitutions.
- Use `String.Join` to rebuild the string with `<br>` between each item.

  ```
  Dim str As String = "~Header~" & vbCrLf & "*content*"
  Dim lines() As String = str.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
      If lines(i).StartsWith("~") And lines(i).EndsWith("~") Then
          lines(i) = "<b>" & lines(i).Substring(1, lines(i).Length - 2) & "</b>"
      End If

      If lines(i).StartsWith("*") And lines(i).EndsWith("*") Then
          lines(i) = "<p>" & lines(i).Substring(1, lines(i).Length - 2) & "</p>"
      End If
  Next
  Dim strNew As String = String.Join("<br>", lines)
  ```

[Edit in response to a comment]

If you want a `<br>` to be added for each blank line, then we need to change the `StringSplitOptions` to `StringSplitOptions.None`. To do that, we need to know exactly what character or characters separate the lines (vbCR, vbLf, vbCrLf), the following code should work if the lines are separated by vbCrLf.

```
    Dim str As String = "~Header~" & vbCrLf & "*content*"
    Dim lines() As String = str.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(i).StartsWith("~") And lines(i).EndsWith("~") Then
            lines(i) = "<b>" & lines(i).Substring(1, lines(i).Length - 2) & "</b>"
        End If

        If lines(i).StartsWith("*") And lines(i).EndsWith("*") Then
            lines(i) = "<p>" & lines(i).Substring(1, lines(i).Length - 2) & "</p>"
        End If
    Next
    Dim strNew As String = String.Join("<br>", lines)
```

Comment: Code's Work! Thank You! but just one small problem, as you can see at the end of every last content there is `2 NextLines`, then in result i would like to put `2 <br/>` too. how it will be possible? Thank You so much!!!

Comment: after a lot of testing i found that this solution is the correct answer. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: but again, looks like `2 NextLine` is not replacing with `2 <br/>` it's just only one `<br/>`.

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what you mean by "NextLine". Is it a carriage return (vbCr or Chr(13)), line feed (vbLf or Chr(10)) or carriage return/linefeed (vbCrLf - two characters: vbCr followed by vbLf)? I wrote my answer to work with any of those possibilities, but if you need to allow for empty lines we need to know what separates the lines. Alternatively, if the string is being read from a text file or a TextBox, you have easier ways of separating the lines.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to get the extra `<br>` for empty lines if the lines are separated by `vbCrLf`

Comment: `NEXTLINE` i mean `ENTER` from keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be useful for something like this:

```
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "~([^~]*)~", "<b>$1</b>")
output = Regex.Replace(output, "\*([^*]*)\*", "<p>$1</p>")
output = Regex.Replace(output, "\r?\n", "<br/>")
```

If would be possible to do the whole operation with single pattern, but you'd need to provide it with a customer `MatchEvaluator` method and it would be more complicated.  So, as long as you don't mind running it through multiple patterns with a different replacement each time, it's simpler and easier.

Comment: `<br/>` is missing after the `Header`?

Comment: Oh, ok.  I see.  For some reason I was confused and thought that you wanted no `<br/>` after the `</b>` and `</p>` tags.  That makes it even easier.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, it’s perfect now, but Obviously `Steven Doggart` and `Blackwood` answers are work perfect. Now I don’t know which one of you guys I will mark as the correct answer. maybe I will base on the best and fastest process. Which one is the best and fast?

Comment: "Best" is a subjective word.  Regex is "better" because it is more configurable (i.e. you could even store the patterns in an external DB or config file) and require less code, so, once you are used to them, they are often easier to read/maintain. They are usually very fast too.  Blackwood's answer could see some improved performance by way of using a well-configured `StringBuilder`, but, depending on the size of the data and the frequency it's called, there probably isn't a big difference in performance between the two.

Comment: But Regex has a bigger learning curve, so if you aren't familiar with it, then you could say that Blackwood's answer is better in that regard.  In any case, since Blackwood answered first, and it's a good answer, and he could use the reputation points more than me, I'd just pick his as the answer and just up-vote mine.

Comment: By the way, do you happen to have control over the format of the input data?  If so, I would strongly recommend using XML instead and considering XSLT as a way to convert the data from XML to HTML.  It would be more standard and more powerful that way.

Comment: no, actually i'm just doing a simple form that will accept an input by format then it will write into text file so i can just copy and paste the generated code for my android project, i will need 1K plus of data and i will need to display it in TextView with html code so i decided to create a form which i just need to input few data and the other is already generated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to your advantage.

```
Function ReplaceSpecial(ByVal text As String) As String
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "^~([^~]+?)~", "<b>$1</b>", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "^\*([^*]+?)\*", "<p>$1</p>", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Return text
End Function
```

Comment: The above code is assuming that each ~ or * you want to replace starts on a new line. If this is not the case then simply remove the `^` from regex (e.g. `"~([^~]+?)~"` instead of `"^~([^~]+?)~"`)